# Call method before tab get switch in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating a sample app. I have a `TestActivity`. Inside this there are subject tabs like `SubjectTab1` and `SubjectTab2`. Each subject tab contain some questions. What i need to do is when i click on  `SubjectTab2` i need to save time spent on `SubjectTab1`. So on which event should i call this time spent method?

here is SaveTimeSpent method

```
public  void SaveTimeSpentOnQue(int queNumber)
{
    if(countDownTimer!=null)
    {
         countDownTimer.cancel();
         countDownTimer=null;
    }

 try {
        lstQuestionTimer=new ArrayList<QuestionList>();
        lstQuestionTimer=QuestionListDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("Number", queNumber)
                                        .and().eq("StudentTestRefrenceID", StudentTestRefrenceID) 
                                        .and().eq("SubjectId", SubjectId).query();

        if(lstQuestionTimer.size()>0)
        {
            for (QuestionList ql : lstQuestionTimer)
            {
                ql.setQueTimeSpent(TestTabFragment.strQueTimeSpent);
                QuestionListDao.update(ql);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Question Time Spent=============="+TestTabFragment.strQueTimeSpent);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about countdown timer ?

Comment: for timer am using CountDownTimer and its working perfectly. I just need to save time when i move to next tab.

Comment: u can then save the time in database or sharedpreferences

Comment: in ondestroyview method of the current tab

Comment: are you using fragments or activities for tabs ?

Comment: then override ondestroyView method of the current fragment and save the time spent

Comment: Not working.My both tabs contain instance of same fragment.

Comment: post your full code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79767/discussion-between-quick-learner-and-meenaxi).

Answer (score 0):

See this Snippet .. life cycle of a `Fragment`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private View view; // retained

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // not cleaning up.
  }
  }
```

so u can use this method to save your data

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        // do your stuff here
    }
```

and read this for more details 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/life-cycle-of-fragment.html

Comment: onDestroyView() not get called. M using same fragment for both tabs.